# Best practice: version numbers for own packages

Tags: packaging

Recently I've started packaging software with [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). The public makefiles can be found on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/brejoc/fpm-makefiles).

But I've a problem with version numbers. When I'm generating a package for e.g. the fish-shell I would have to make clear, that the original version of the package hasn't changed, but that this would be the e.g. second package I've generated, so that it can replace the previously generated package.

Is there a best practice or convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is :

```
debian_revision  

          This part of the version number specifies  the  version  of  the
          Debian  package  based  on the upstream version.  It may contain
          only alphanumerics and the characters + . ~  (plus,  full  stop,
          tilde)  and  is compared in the same way as the upstream_version
          is.

          It is optional; if it isn’t present  then  the  upstream_version
          may not contain a hyphen.  This format represents the case where
          a piece of software was written specifically to be turned into a
          Debian  package,  and so there is only one "debianisation" of it
          and therefore no revision indication is required.

          It is conventional to restart the debian_revision  at  ’1’  each
          time time the upstream_version is increased.

          Dpkg  will  break the version number apart at the last hyphen in
          the string (if there is one) to determine  the  upstream_version
          and  debian_revision.  The absence of a debian_revision compares
          earlier  than  the  presence  of  one   (but   note   that   the
          debian_revision  is  the  least  significant part of the version
          number).
```

[Reference](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/deb-version.5.html)

Comment: So my version for fish should look like this?
fish_1.23~git.7abf6c71ad113affcfbb101c80e309d1aaa4bddb~brejoc4

Comment: It is not probably a good thing to do as your revision number will not be strictly increasing. It would recommend using the date instead, for instance.

Comment: brejoc - the git commit number is one possibility.  while i like @Thomas's idea about date stamping your build number you run in to needing to respin loads of packages if it's a common dependency (or rebuild lots of stuff with a >= if it's not already there) so you don't have loads of mismatched build dependencies (just search the site here for dependency problems and look at how many have dates in the version numbers)

Comment: Well if you intend to support upgrade through unstable / git tagged experimental version, you still need to have an order in your package versioning scheme which is not the case when using Git commit number... As for dates as version number, see Debian policy 4.1: http://www.fifi.org/doc/debian-policy/policy.html/ch-versions.html

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't saying you were wrong or disagreeing.  I was saying something about why versioning policy is relatively gray.

Comment: Wow, this is confusing - but I thing I'm starting to understand this better. Thanks @ThomasMoulard, you are right. The revision is a bad version number. I think I will stick with your suggestion and do something like this: `fish_1.23~git20130508`
But if something goes wrong, I'll need to rebuild a package with the same date/revision again. Is this what I'll use the debian revision for? Like: `fish_1.23~git20130508-brejoc1`

Comment: The rule is: as long as upstream (the original software) is not updated *only* the debian revision number should be incremented. So yes, exactly.